# Open Dialog when drop down was changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, razor

I am trying to open a pop up (some dialog) when the user changes the drop down list from the default value which is male to female.
I used the JS code from a previous post but nothing happens, in the inspect element I get message that tells me there is no dialog, any idea how to make it work?
I've also tried with an alert but nothing happens either when I change the selection in the drop down list...
I'm very new to JS and Jquery ...

```
public class Ad
    {
        public int Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Gender
        {
            get
            {
                return new[]
                {
                    new SelectListItem {Value = "M", Text = "Male"},
                    new SelectListItem {Value = "F", Text = "Female"}
                };
            }
        }
```

The Index.cshtml code.

```
@model IEnumerable<Ad.Models.Ad>
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#M').change(function () {
                if ($(this).val() === "F") {
                    alert("I am an alert box!");
                    dialog.dialog('open');
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
<h3>My APP</h3>


p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {

    }


    @*<br style="margin-bottom:240px;" />*@
    @Html.ActionLink("Create", "Create",
        null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "mybtn" })
    <p>

    </p>


    <style type="text/css">
        a.mybtn {
            background: #fa0088;


        }
    </style>

  <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Gender)
     </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>


   @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.Geneder, item.Gender, new { id = "M" })

                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
                </td>

            </tr>
```

Comment: do you get the alert?

Comment: NO noting happen what can be the problem...

Comment: So the first problem is with `if ($(this).val() === "F") {` I think. Comment out the `dialog.dialog('open');` code and check for the alert. also try alerting `$(this).val()` value before the `if` statement

Comment: Also where has this `dialog` variable come? Normally we have to place a div with an id as dialog and the `dialog` varable equals to `$('#dialog')`

Comment: I have change it to the following code and still nothing happen can you check please and let me know if this is exactly what you mean       <script type="text/javascript">
    Breakpoint;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("M").change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "F") {
                $(this).val()
                alert("I am an alert box!");
                //dialog.dialog('open');

            }
        });
    });

</script>

Comment: I mean `<script type="text/javascript">  $(document).ready(function () { $("#M").change(function () { alert($(this).val()); alert($(this).val() == "F"); if ($(this).val() == "F") { $(this).val() alert("I am an alert box!"); //dialog.dialog('open'); } }); }); </script>`

Comment: @gaurav - Can you please write it as answer since when I copy it from the comment I got errors in the code :(

Comment: @gaurav - I was able to fix it and this was solve the problem please put is as answer so I can colse it,thanks,btw I have addtional question which I'll open in 2 min can you please check if you can help,thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the problem occurs when there is no div with an id as 'dialog'. The javascript variable should be initialized as `dialog = $('#dialog')`

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(document).ready(function () { 
     $("#M").change(function () { 
          alert($(this).val());  
          alert($(this).val() == "F"); 
     if ($(this).val() == "F") { 
             alert("I am an alert box!");
              //dialog.dialog('open'); //commenting out this line would tell where the problem lies.
       } 
    }); 
  }); 
</script>
```

**update:**  To make it applied to the multiple select boxes, you should use class selector eg `.M` of jQuery instead of id selector `#M`. For that first we need to give same class  **M** all the select boxes.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.Geneder, item.Gender, new { id = "M", @class = "M" })
```

Now change  `$("#M").change(function () {` to `$(".M").change(function () {`.

Comment: Voted up and mark as answer :) ,one last question regard this issue,I have table why its work just to the first entry of the table? the drop down for the second entry in the table is not working

Comment: because `$('#M')` returns only first element with the id as `M`. You should put some class as `@Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.Geneder, item.Gender, new { id = "M", @class = "M" })`. Now change `$('#M')` with `$('.M')`. Now it should apply on every dropdown with a css class `M`.

Answer (score 0):

`$('#M')` replace with `$('select')`

Comment: No need to change `#M` it's drop down's Id.

Comment: just tried http://jsfiddle.net/4REJn/. i think problem in somewhere else your code.may i know which language of coding you using?

Comment: Currently I've create MVC5 application and this code is in the view index.cshtml

Comment: check you code formatted OK in viewsource. and check you get alert or not after commenting dialog code.